# Paging not updating when data is empty ZK

Tags: java, paging, zk

I recently got assigned to maintaining an app at work which uses ZK Framework. Just getting into it.

It's made with pure Java, no zul. Mostly divided into Richlet and Render classes.

I have a grid that shows info based on search parameters. When two subsequent searches have results, the paging refreshes correctly, but when I perform a search with results, and a search without results afterwards, the information disappears (as expected) but the paging stays the same. For example, if the first search returned 18 pages of data, the second search (with no data) clears the grid but the 18 empty pages stay. Isn't setModel supposed to refresh paging?

This loads the results into the grid:

```
protected void loadProperties(List<GdiLogDTO> lista, Boolean keepActualPage) {
    if (!keepActualPage) {
        ZKDisplayUtils.cleanComponent(this.ventana);
        this.drawGrid();
    }
    grid.setModel(new SimpleListModel(lista));
}
```

And this is where the grid is created:

```
this.grid = new Grid();
grid.setMold("paging");
grid.setPageSize(15);
grid.setSclass("tabla");
grid.setOddRowSclass("oddClass");
grid.setStyle("border:1px solid #CECECE");
grid.setRowRenderer(new GdiLogsRender());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like issue [ZK-1869](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-1869) - likely fixed since version 6.5.4
Which version are you using?